# Save Data in Database using Unit Of Work Pattern

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-core-2.2

I have try to save data from database using Unit OF Work Pattern.But I got error.My code is:

Unit of Work code:

```
    private PousadaManagementContext MinhaPousadaContext { get; }
    public IPousadaRepository PousadaRepository { get; private set; }


       public UnitOfWork
        (
        PousadaManagementContext minhaPousadaContext,
        IPousadaRepository pousadaRepository           
        )
        {
        this.MinhaPousadaContext = minhaPousadaContext;
        PousadaRepository = pousadaRepository;           
        }

        public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
       {
        return await MinhaPousadaContext.SaveChangesAsync();
       }

       public int Complete()
       {
        return MinhaPousadaContext.SaveChanges();
      }

     public void Dispose() => MinhaPousadaContext.Dispose();



     public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
     {
       int Complete();
       Task<int> CompleteAsync ();
     }
```

businessclass:

```
    private UnitOfWork managementUoW { get;  }
    public PousadaBusiness(IUnitOfWork ManagementUoW)
    {
        ManagementUoW = managementUoW;
    }


    public async Task<Pousada> Save(Pousada p)
    {           
        return await managementUoW.PousadaRepository.Save(p);           
    }
```

Here In Save method  p all properties have value but managementUoW is null.
How to Solve this error.

Comment: Looks like a typo, you are passing `ManagementUoW` as parameter instead of  `managementUoW`, so the assignment is in the wrong order.

Comment: how will........

Comment: Can you Explain?

Comment: If this is your exact code then managementUoW is never assigned. Replace `ManagementUoW = managementUoW;` with `managementUoW = ManagementUoW;`. Note the uppercase/lowercase m.

Comment: I follow your instruction.Hence, My error has been solved.Thanks.